# Количество значений класса ENUM

Tags: c#, enum

Есть некий **ENUM** класс вида:

```
public enum Numbers
{
    ONE = 1,
    TWO = 2,
    THREE = 3,
    FOUR = 4,
    FIVE = 5
}
```

Как узнать количество значений в списке перечисления? Просьба **hardcode** не предлагать.

P.S. В Java я могу взять весь список массивом и после узнать размер массива. Всё делается одной строчкой. Пример:

```
Numbers.values().length;
```

В Шарпе ума не приложу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
var enumCount = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Numbers)).Length;
```

Answer (score 2):

можно так:

```
string[] tempEnumArray = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Numbers)); //превратим ваш enum в массив строк
int enumLen = tempEnumArray.GetLength(); // а вот теперь получим количество
```

Answer (score 2):

Или так:

```
var count = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Numbers)).Length;
```

А так можно проитерировать по значениям:

```
foreach (Numbers e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Numbers)))
    Console.WriteLine(e + " = " + (int)e);
```